# Explicit local normal form symplectomorphism at torus fixed point of a coadjoint orbit

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, torus-action, moment-map

Let $K$ be a compact, connected (probably also simple) Lie group and with a maximal torus $T$. Regular coadjoint orbits $\mathcal{O}_{\lambda} \cong K/T$, parameterized by a regular element $\lambda \in \mathfrak{t}^*$, have several properties:

- They are symplectic, equipped with KKS forms.
- They are Hamiltonian $T$-manifolds with respect to the coadjoint action of $T$, generated by the canonical projection map $\mathcal{O}_{\lambda} \to \mathfrak{t}^*$.
- The fixed points of the $T$-action are precisely the elements of $\mathcal{O}_{\lambda} \cap \mathfrak{t}^*$ (where $\mathfrak{t}^*$ is identified with the subspace $(\mathfrak{k}^*)^T$).
- Using the killing form (or whatever scalar multiple of it that you like), we can make an identification  $T_{\lambda}\mathcal{O}_{\lambda} \cong \mathfrak{t}^{\perp}$. One has that $\mathfrak{t}^{\perp}$ is invariant under the adjoint action of $T$ and coincides under this identification with the isotropy action of $T$ at the fixed point $\lambda$.

The local normal form theorem for Hamiltonian torus actions tells us that there exists a symplectomorphism $\varphi$ from a neighbourhood of 0 in the  symplectic vector space $T_{\lambda}\mathcal{O}_{\lambda}$ to a neighbourhood of $\lambda$ in $\mathcal{O}_{\lambda}$ such that:

1. $\varphi$ is $T$-equivariant.
2. $\varphi$ intertwines the moment maps, i.e. if $\mu = \phi + \lambda$ denotes the quadratic moment map for the isotropy action of $T$ on $T_{\lambda}\mathcal{O}_{\lambda}$ shifted by $\lambda$, and $\text{pr}\colon \mathcal{O}_{\lambda} \to \mathfrak{t}^*$, then 
   $$ \text{pr} \circ \varphi = \mu.$$

Since everything in this example is fairly explicit, it seems reasonable to ask for an explicit formula for the map $\varphi$.

> What is a general formula for $\varphi$?

There is an ``obvious candidate'' that looks good at first: one can easily define the map
$$\psi\colon \mathfrak{t}^{\perp} \to \mathcal{O}_{\lambda}, \, \psi(X) = Ad^*_{e^X}\lambda.$$
This map is $T$-equivariant, but it fails to be symplectic (which can be demonstrated easily for coadjoint orbits of $SU(2)$).

(As a side note, the killing form restricted to $\mathfrak{t}^{\perp}$ and then extended $\mathcal{O}_{\lambda}$ by $K$-invariance makes $\mathcal{O}_{\lambda}$ a reductive homogeneous space, and  $\psi$ is in fact the exponential map for this metric.)

I believe that, essentially, the map $\psi$ fails to be symplectic because $e^Xe^Y \neq e^{X+Y}$ if $[X,Y]\neq 0$ (which, if you are not careful means that you can accidentally ``prove'' this map is symplectic and spend an afternoon being very confused), which suggests that maybe there is some sort of CBH-related correction to $\psi$ that makes it symplectic (I am really just taking a guess here).

Edit: It will be sufficient to find a $T$-equivariant map $\rho\colon \mathfrak{t}^{\perp} \to K$ such that
$$\varphi(Y) := Ad_{\rho(Y)}\lambda$$
satisfies the condition 
$$ d(\varphi)_Y(ad_X\lambda) = ad_{Ad_{\rho(Y)}X}\varphi(Y).$$

Edit 2: Unpacking the proof of local normal forms, one sees that there exists a map $\phi\colon U \to \mathfrak{t}^{\perp}$ defined on a neighbourhood $U$ of the origin in $\mathfrak{t}^{\perp}$ that fixes the origin and is a diffeomorphism onto it's image, such that the map

$$\varphi(Y) := Ad_{e^{\phi(Y)}}\lambda$$

is a symplectomorphism. $\phi$ is the time-1 flow of a moser vector field. It's not clear from this perspective whether an explicit formula for $\phi$ is a reasonable thing to hope for.

Edit 3: I found a partial answer that I've posted below, but I am interested if anyone can expand on it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial answer.

The map $\mathfrak{t}^{\perp} \to T_{\lambda}\mathcal{O}_{\lambda}$, $X \mapsto ad_X(\lambda)$, endows $\mathfrak{t}^{\perp}$ with a linear symplectic form 
$$ \omega_0(X,Y) = \langle \lambda, [X,Y]\rangle.$$
Based on edit 2 above, we know there exists a $T$-equivariant map $\phi\colon \mathfrak{t}^{\perp} \to \mathfrak{t}^{\perp}$ (at least, defined and invertible near 0) such that $\phi(0) = 0$ and the composition $$\varphi(Y) := Ad_{e^{\phi(Y)}}\lambda$$
 is a symplectomorphism.

> **Example ($K = SU(2)$)**  Here we can compute using cylindrical coordinates on the coadjoint orbit and polar coordinates on
>   $\mathfrak{t}^{\perp}$ to show that  $$\phi\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 &
>  \rho e^{i\theta} \\ -\rho e^{-i\theta} & 0 \end{array}\right)\right) =
>  \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & \arcsin(\rho) e^{i\theta} \\
>  -\arcsin(\rho) e^{-i\theta} & 0 \end{array}\right).$$

Let $\pi\colon K \to \mathcal{O}_{\lambda}$ be the map $k \mapsto Ad_k\lambda$. We know that

- $d(\pi)_e Y = ad_Y\lambda$
- $d(\pi)_k = d(Ad_k)_{\lambda} \circ d(\pi)_e \circ d(\mathcal{L}_{k^{-1}})_k$ (where $\mathcal{L}_k\colon K \to K$ is left multiplication).
- $d(\mathcal{L}_{k^{-1}})_k$ is simply the (left-invariant) Maurer-Cartan form $\theta$ evaluated at $k$
- Because it is a linear map, $d(Ad_k)_{\lambda} = Ad_k$. We also know that $Ad_kad_X \lambda = ad_{Ad_kX}Ad_k\lambda$.

Thus:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        d(\varphi)_Y & = d(\pi)_{e^{\phi(Y)}} \circ d(\exp)_{\phi(Y)}\circ d\phi_Y\\
        & = d(Ad_{e^{\phi(Y)}})_{\lambda} \circ d(\pi)_e \circ d(\mathcal{L}_{e^{-\phi(Y)}})_{e^{\phi(Y)}} \circ d(\exp)_{\phi(Y)}\circ d\phi_Y\\ 
        & = Ad_{e^{\phi(Y)}}\left(d(\pi)_e \circ \theta_{e^{\phi(Y)}} \circ d(\exp)_{\phi(Y)}\circ d\phi_Y\right)\\
        & = Ad_{e^{\phi(Y)}}\left(ad_{\theta_{e^{\phi(Y)}} \circ d(\exp)_{\phi(Y)}\circ d\phi_Y}\lambda\right)\\
        & = ad_{Ad_{e^{\phi(Y)}}\left(\theta_{e^{\phi(Y)}} \circ d(\exp)_{\phi(Y)}\circ d\phi_Y\right)}\left(Ad_{e^{\phi(Y)}}\lambda\right).
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

The map $\varphi$ is a symplectomorphism if $\varphi^* \omega = \omega_0$. Explicitly, for $X,Z \in \mathfrak{t}^{\perp}$, 
$$(\varphi^*\omega)_Y(X,Z) = \omega_{\varphi(Y)}\left(d(\varphi)_Y X,d(\varphi)_Y Z\right)$$
which by the previous equation
$$ = \langle Ad_{e^{\phi(Y)}}\lambda, [Ad_{e^{\phi(Y)}}\left(\theta_{e^{\phi(Y)}} \circ d(\exp)_{\phi(Y)}\circ d\phi_Y X\right), Ad_{e^{\phi(Y)}}\left(\theta_{e^{\phi(Y)}} \circ d(\exp)_{\phi(Y)}\circ d\phi_Y Z\right)]\rangle$$
$$ = \langle \lambda, [\theta_{e^{\phi(Y)}} \circ d(\exp)_{\phi(Y)}\circ d\phi_Y X, \theta_{e^{\phi(Y)}} \circ d(\exp)_{\phi(Y)}\circ d\phi_Y Z]\rangle.$$
This simplifies by substituting the formula for the derivative of the exponential map:
$$\theta_{e^{\phi(Y)}} \circ d(\exp)_{\phi(Y)} = e^{-\phi(Y)}e^{\phi(Y)}\left(\frac{1-e^{-ad_{\phi(Y)}}}{ad_{\phi(Y)}}\right) = \frac{1-e^{-ad_{\phi(Y)}}}{ad_{\phi(Y)}}$$
to give 
$$(\varphi^*\omega_{\lambda})_Y(X,Z) = \bigg\langle \lambda, \frac{1-e^{-ad_{\phi(Y)}}}{ad_{\phi(Y)}}[  d\phi_Y X, d\phi_Y Z]\bigg\rangle.$$

> Thus, our equation for $\phi$ is  \begin{equation}  \bigg\langle
>  \lambda, \frac{1-e^{-ad_{\phi(Y)}}}{ad_{\phi(Y)}}[  d\phi_Y X, d\phi_Y
>  Z]\bigg\rangle = \langle \lambda, [X,Z]\rangle. \end{equation}

The series expansion of the LHS will have some terms that disappear because they pair with $\lambda$ to zero, but I don't have a general formula for the ones that remain.